# How do I reference a vector from a map's value?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<string> examplevector {"one", "two", "three"};
  map<string, vector<string>> examplemap {{"vector1", examplevector}};

  examplemap["vector1"][0] = "eight";

  cout << examplemap["vector1"][0] << endl; // prints "eight"
  cout << examplevector[0] << endl; // prints "one". I was expecting "eight".

}
```

Is there a way to alter the values within examplevector via examplemap["vector1"]?

Comment: The map stores a copy of `examplevector`. When you assigned to `examplemap["vector1"][0]`, you modified that copy, not the original.

Comment: Ah right. Is there no way for the map to refer to the original?

Comment: Well, you could have `map<string, vector<string>*>` and adjust your code accordingly. That is, the map would store pointers to vectors, not vectors themselves. Of course you have to ensure that the pointed-to vectors actually outlive those pointers. Taking a step back - why do you want that? What problem are you ultimately trying to solve? The question as written sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You could take a reference to an element in the map. Like `auto& vec = examplemap["vector1"]`. But if the element is removed from the map, the reference is no longer valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C++ does not work this way, this is not how objects work in C++. This is how objects work in Java and C#, but C++ is not Java or C#. Objects that are stored in some container, a vector, a map, or any other container, are distinct objects of their own and have nothing to do with any other object.

```
map<string, vector<string>> examplemap {{"vector1", examplevector}};
```

This effectively makes a copy of the `examplevector` and stores it in the map. Changes to the object in the map have no effect on the original `examplevector`. Similarly:

```
string abra="cadabra";

std::vector<std::string> examplevector{"hocuspocus", abra};

// ...
examplevector[1]="abracadabra";
```

This modifies the object in the vector. `abra` is still `cadabra`.

It's possible to store a map or a container of pointers, or perhaps `std::reference_wrapper`s. Then, modify the pointed-to object, or wrapped reference, will modify the underlying object. But that introduces its own kind of complexity, in terms of managing the lifetime of all objects, correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter the values of `examplevector` via your map you should declare your map as a map of strings associated to vector pointers, therefore you can alter the original vector using its reference in the map.

Adapting your code, it will become like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<string>* examplevector = new vector<string>({"one", "two", "three"});
  map<string, vector<string>*> examplemap = {{"vector1", examplevector}};

  examplemap["vector1"]->at(0) = "eight";

  cout << examplemap["vector1"]->at(0) << endl; // prints "eight"
  cout << examplevector->at(0) << endl; // prints "eigth", as expected.

}
```